# Inspect Java HTTP connection pool

Tags: java, http, persistent, connection

HttpUrlConnection uses persistent connections by default (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html).
Is there any way to inspect Java HTTP connection pool? Eg check how many open connections in the pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. In Oracle's VM, you can in theory inspect the static cache in `sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.kac` using reflection. This is a `Map`, which values are `Stack`s of cached `HttpClient` instances. The cache however also contains already closed or timed out connections and it does not seem to be a reasonable easy way to filter these out, without actually performing a real HTTP request, in which case abandoned connections will automatically reconnect.